# Eclipse Android: how to use an Animation Scale Code?

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, scale

Now I wanted to use an effect, that the letter "i" of the word "Ecl pse" appears firstly bigger and gets smaller, after I clicked on the button. But with the following code the whole word "Eclipse" is bigger and gets smaller then

```
public class Pagetwo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public Button btn;
    public TextView tw;
    Animation a;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pagetwo);



        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnKlick);
        tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvhallo);
        a= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Ecl pse");  

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String text = tw.getText().toString();
        int n = 3; 
        String newText = text.substring(0, n) + "i" + text.substring(n + 1);

        tw.setText(newText);


            tw.startAnimation(a);





        {}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't defining your animation in the correct place nor are you applying it to the text view.

Try this:

```
public class Pagetwo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public Button btn1;
public TextView tw1;
Animation a; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnKlick);
    tw1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvhallo);
    a= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tw1.setText("Hallo");
    tw1.startAnimation(a);

}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working. But do you know how to edit it, that only one letter has this Animation. So I want the letter "i" of the word "Ecl pse" appears firstly bigger and gets smaller. I edited my Java-Code, so that the "i" appears... See above.